# Закрыть от индексации папку, которая повторяется в разных каталогах

Tags: robots.txt

Есть сайт и в каждом разделе размещена папка admin.
Если прописываю Disallow: /admin/, закрывает индексацию только в одном разделе - site.com/admin/, а в остальных разделах остается открытой.
Подскажите, можно ли одной строкой закрыть от индексации эту папку в каждом разделе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этих правил должно быть достаточно:

```
Disallow: */admin/*
Disallow: */admin$
```

Одной строкой `Disallow: */admin/*` можно обойтись если Вы гарантируете, что урлы приложения всегда закрываются при помощи `/`.